# R: Specifying bins for table (or easier breaks for hist?)

Tags: r

I have two vectors of integers, for example:

```
a <- c(1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 15, 15)
b <- c(1, 15, 15, 15, 15)
```

I want to find the table/hist counts for each of them. However, I want the bins to be identical between them. So, ideally, I would get

```
> ff(a, c(1, 7, 15))
names = 1, 7, 15
counts = 2, 4, 2

> ff(b, c(1, 7, 15))
names = 1, 7, 15
counts = 1, 0, 4
```

If I use hist I need to specify weird breaks (c(0.5, 1.5, 7.5, 15.5)). If I use table I need to match the names afterward (because table(b) returns names = 1, 15, counts = 1, 4, ignoring the 7). How can I bridge the gap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to a factor and specify the levels....

```
a <- c(1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 15, 15)
b <- c(1, 15, 15, 15, 15)
levs <- c(1,7,15)

table( factor( a , levels = levs ) )
# 1  7 15 
# 2  4  2
table( factor( b , levels = levs ) )
# 1  7 15 
# 1  0  4
```

Comment: Of course! R's motto should be "Now you're thinking with factors". Thank you.